# How to pass js var in xslt

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I have a javascript variable something like:

```
var str = "AA,BB,CC,AA,BB,DD";
        var totlength = str.split(",").length;
        var xx = str.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < totlength; i++) {
            alert(xx[i]);   

        }
```

and I could print this value using above method.Now the problem is I have to craete one `<ul><li>` structure using xslt and `<li>` should get populated with this js values.
so the structure will be something like-

```
<ul>
<li>AA</li>
<li>BB</li>
<li>CC</li>
<li>AA</li>
</ul>
```

so the stucture will be in xslt and value will come from js, and i am writing this ina xslt file (no separate js file).How to achieve this.

Comment: What does Javascript have to do with XSLT?

Comment: Could you provide further details, like the XML input file, and maybe the XSL you want to update?

Comment: no need of xml file as such.you can hardcode <ul><li> in xslt.
<ul><li>val from Js </li></Ul>

Comment: I'm not sure you can; you're XSL markup needs to be valid, ie every <ul> or <li> opened in XSL must be closed as well, and not from JS

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There is no link with XLT in this case;</strike> I guess you can achieve what you want with something like:

```
<xsl:template match="LIST">
  <div id="myDiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var str = "<xsl:value-of select="."/>";

    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    var totlength = str.split(",").length;
    var xx = str.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < totlength; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li") ;
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xx[i])) ;    
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(list);
    </script>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

with the XML file containing the `LIST` markup:

```
<LIST>AA,BB,CC</LIST>
```

Comment: @Wondering what about this one? or do you mean that you want to get rid of the JS script, and want to build you're list only with XSLT?

Comment: @Wondering: You can pass parameters to XSLT stylesheet with javascript. In this case just the string (in case there is no posiblity to get this from some XML resource...) Then tokenize and transform with XSLT. Search about passing parameter with your target browsers, and XSLT tokenize.